# Codeigniter page shows 404 page not found

Tags: linux, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and Linux as well. When I tried to run `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/hello/first_page` it shows `404 Error: Page not found`. My Controller class :

```
/*hello.php*/
class Hello extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function first_page()
    {
        $this->load->view('first_view');
    }
}
```

And my `first_view.php` is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First CI Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi Folks !
    </body>

<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */   

?>
</html>
```

NB: `http://localhost/CodeIgniter` shows the welcome message.And all files are executable(777)

Comment: Two things to check first, your apache config to see if htaccess is enabled and your .htaccess to see if it's configured correctly. Please post the relevant sections for your directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this url.. You'll get it

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/hello/first_page
```

You have to include `index.php`